# Criar link com cakephp dentro de jquery?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2

Como criar um link usando as convenções do CakePHP dentro de JQuery ?

Estou tentando assim mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url("/Empresas/indexAjax.json");?>",
            dataSrc:""
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "Empresa.id"},
            {"data": "Empresa.nomeFantasia"},
            {"data": "Empresa.cnpj"},
            {"data": "Empresa.telefone1"},
            {"data": "Empresa.telefone2"},
            {"data": "Empresa.celular"},
            {"data": "Empresa.aberto"},
            {"data":null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "render": function(obj) {
                    return "<?php echo $this->Html->link('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>',
                                                        array('action' => 'view', obj["Empresa"].id), 
                                                        array('title'=>'view', 'escape' => false)); ?>";

                    //return '<a href=/Produto/Detalhar/' + o["Empresa"].id + '>' + 'More' + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

para usar caminhos de url do cakephp no javascript é simples, use o caminho apenas :-)

```
 url: "/Empresas/indexAjax.json"
```

pois quem vai interpretar a rota para a requisição javascript é o cakephp!

num script separado de `.js` não dá para executar código php por isso que não está funcionando como desejado, se for em algum momento usar codigo php dentro de javascript você precisa ter o javascript num documento .html ou .php EX:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      alert("o dobro de 5 é <?php echo '10'?>");
   }):
</script>

</head>
<!-- resto do html imaginário -->
```

Espero ter ajudado. abraço